# Are there any tutorials on where I can model low poly hair like this?

Tags: modeling, shaders, hair, pose-mode, polycount

[image]

Just have been having the hardest time trying to model hair, and cant find any tutorials for low poly hair like this.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for [tutorials, links or videos is considered off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62) here. Instead of asking an indirect question, could you reformulate your post to directly  ask about the issue you are trying to solve, rather than point you to some resource?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

- Create a UV sphere (here 16/8 vertices), cut it off, extrude the faces to give it thickness:

[image]

Pull down the edges to create hair peaks:

[image]

Scale 1 out of 2 edges:

[image]

maybe triangulate the topology with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or try the *Decimate* modifier:

[image]

Comment: holy shit thank u so much

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: how do you extrude all the faces like that? do u extrude from the inside or outside? @moonboots

Comment: yes select all, Alt E and extrude along normals for example